# unable to get onchange() to work in woocommerce

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to detect if the value in the billing country dropdown box has changed in woocommerce checkout fields. If it has changed, get the value of the country that the user has selected and then do something about it.

To do this, I'm using jquery code as follows:

```
    $('#billing_country').on('change',function() {
        alert(this.value);
        // do something like alerting users that the book can not be shipped to the selected country.
    });
```

Below is the HTML code I found in the checkout form page of woocommerce.

```
    <select id="billing_country" class="country_to_state country_select " name="billing_country" tabindex="-1" title="Country *" style="display: none;">
    <option value="">Select a country…</option>
    <option value="AX">Åland Islands</option>
    <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="AL">Albania</option> 
    ...
```

The problem with the above code is that when I select a different country from the dropdown box, nothing happened at all.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: `style="display: none;"` what is the meaning of this?

Comment: which version of jquery are you using?

Answer (score 0):

See this response: [Run javascript code on billing country change in WooCommerce checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66697630/run-javascript-code-on-billing-country-change-in-woocommerce-checkout)

You need to delegate your event to the document body, otherwise WooCommerce will block your code on checkout.

As WooCommerce JS code uses already jQuery, try the following:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(document.body).on('change', 'select[name=billing_country]', function(){
        console.log('Country changed: '+$(this).val());
        // Here run your function or code
    });
});
```