# Run javascript code on billing country change in WooCommerce checkout

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

Hey all I am trying to run a function and display a message when a user selects any other country than the US. However, I'm stuck as I can't even get the select box to log the event on changing of the country. Here's my code:

```
function checkIfInternational(e) {
  console.log(e);
}
const shipCountry = document.querySelector("#billing_country"); //Logs the select box

shipCountry.addEventListener("change", checkIfInternational); // listening for the change event
```

Any ideas on why this is happening? Is Woocommerce preventing JS from running on the page or something?

Edit: JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/suoc57mg/1/

Comment: What is inside element with id #billing_country.. this is default select or something else ?

Comment: It's a default select box with options for countries.

Comment: Why do you define `const` (constant) instead of `var` (variable)?

Comment: It's a small JS file for just some basic checkout page customizations. Why recommend using the old `var`?

Comment: Are you linked this file to the page ?

Comment: Where are you using your code? in WooCommerce checkout page I suppose, right?

Comment: Hey Loic, Yes I have file called checkout.js that loads only on the checkout screen. I can log the `select` on page load, but nothing happens on the change event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to delegate your event to the document body, otherwise WooCommerce will block your code on checkout.

As WooCommerce JS code uses already jQuery, try the following:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(document.body).on('change', 'select[name=billing_country]', function(){
        console.log('Country changed: '+$(this).val());
        // Here run your function or code
    });
});
```

It should work now.

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much, Loic! Does Woocommerce purposefully block JS code from running for security?

Comment: @Sackadelic No but there are already a lot of delegated events in WooCommerce that takes the hand over yours.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that your #billing_country element looks like this:

```html
 <select id="billing_country">
    <option value="US">United State</option>
    <option value="PL">Poland</option>
    <option value="DU">Germany</option>
    <option value="ES">Estonia</option>
    <option value="RU">Mather Russia</option>
 </select>
```

You can check its value by target's value of event which you handle in this way.

```js
document.getElementById("billing_country")?.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  if (event.target.value !== "US") {
    // not united state :(
  }
});
```

Comment: The problem is that no code is running at all on the change event. I tried your method as well and nothing logs to the console.

Comment: Are you sure that #billing_country exists ? Can you provide a minimum version of the reproduction of the code you are having trouble with?

Comment: There's an edit I made with a link to a JS fiddle. However, it works in JSF...so something is preventing the code from running on Woo?

Comment: Either you have not linked your script to the page or the select element is created after your script has been executed. Be sure that your script is after whole body content.

Comment: It is, and I can log the selectbox like normal on page refresh. It would break if I was loading the JS file first.